# Remove foreign key sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I understand the code remove the constraint

`ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DROP CONSTRAINT <FOREIGN_KEY_NAME>`

But I do not know my FK name I did not give it one and have read that is given one automatically.

How can I find this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are asking about SQL Server, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @table_name varchar(50) = 'MyTable'
DECLARE @fk_name varchar(100)
SELECT @fk_name = CONSTRAINT_NAME 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS 
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table_name AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE='FOREIGN KEY'

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(200) = 'ALTER TABLE [' + @table_name + '] DROP CONSTRAINT [' + @fk_name + ']'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```